# Facebook don't get correct description an image on share for URLS that are DNS web-alias?

Tags: facebook, dns, share

Facebook doesn't get correct description for an image on share for URLs that are DNS web-alias.

See http://anon-chat.thibaultjanbeyer.com/

- Inferred Property The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
- Inferred Property The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
- Inferred Property The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

The Facebook object debugger gives:

Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties

- og:url    http://anon-chat.thibaultjanbeyer.com/
- og:type   website
- og:title  anon-chat.thibaultjanbeyer.com
- og:description    Your user agent does not support frames or is currently configured not to display frames. However you may visit the page that was supposed to be here
- og:updated_time   1435088030

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: That URL contains only a frameset (no idea why you would think this was a _“DNS web-alias”_, because this has nothing whatsoever to do with DNS), and the actual URL is http://kit.thibaultjanbeyer.com/tools/anon-chat/

Comment: Because that's what I've chosen in my control pannel @ one.com.. See the Screenshot: http://kit.thibaultjanbeyer.com/screen.png guess I'll have to write with the support @one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL does not have any Open Graph tags that are visible to our crawler (see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fanon-chat.thibaultjanbeyer.com%2F)).

Add the tags and you should be fine. If you have no control over the HTML at http://anon-chat.thibaultjanbeyer.com/, you're out of luck.